# Surface tension of a single layer of atoms

Tags: atoms, surface-tension

Suppose somehow we take a layer of liquid in such a way that the layer is just one layer of the liquid atoms, will there be any surface tension?

Comment: But then how can one say that the layer is in a 'liquid' state? Don't we need a bulk to identify a state as a liquid?

Comment: Really? Do we? I'm not sure but seems like you've got a point

Comment: In case of liquid-vapor interface, we need a density gradient of liquid molecules near the interface which leads to surface tension. This gradient would be absent here.

Comment: Surface tension is a "bulk" phenomenon.  A single layer of atoms is not in the "bulk" state.

Comment: I don't think you could actually call it surface tension, but given no other forces, wouldn't the atoms tend to hold a distance from each other that balances atomic attraction / repulsion? But the atoms would probably form a sphere, with no other forces